# how can I extract a pattern only using grep

Tags: linux, unix, grep

How can we extract the contents present inside KeyProviderType tag only using grep command from the folllowing pattern?

```
<ContentProtectKeyProfiles-row><Name>PREM7</Name><Domain>42.0.112.121</Domain<ProfileType>4</ProfileType>
<Protocol>HTTP</Protocol><Port>80</Port><KeyProviderType>HLS-AES-128</KeyProviderType</ContentProtectKeyProfiles-row>
```

Comment: the exact pattern is 

<ContentProtectKeyProfiles-row>
    <Name>PREM7</Name>
    <Domain>42.0.112.121</Domain>
    <ProfileType>4</ProfileType>
    <Protocol>HTTP</Protocol>
    <Port>80</Port>
<KeyProviderType>HLS-AES-128</KeyProviderType>
</ContentProtectKeyProfiles-row>

Comment: is it just the last 11 characters? you need to show how other lines look like so that we know what to grep and what not.

Comment: the value for the tag </KeyProviderType></KeyProviderType> which is HLS-AES-128 over here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extracting node values using XSLT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17287495/extracting-node-values-using-xslt)

Answer (score 1):

```
a@x:/tmp$ cat s.xml
<ContentProtectKeyProfiles-row> <Name>PREM7</Name> <Domain>42.0.112.121</Domain> <ProfileType>4</ProfileType> <Protocol>HTTP</Protocol> <Port>80</Port> <KeyProviderType>HLS-AES-128</KeyProviderType> </ContentProtectKeyProfiles-row>dhruv@dhruv-pathak:/tmp$ 
a@x:/tmp$ cat s.xml | grep -oe  "<KeyProviderType>.*</KeyProviderType>"
<KeyProviderType>HLS-AES-128</KeyProviderType>
```

Comment: the output should be only HLS-AES-128

Comment: `... | tr '<>' ' ' | awk '{print $2}'`

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `grep` to process XML files. Use a proper XML parser. For example, using [xsh](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aXSH2), I can just run

```
open in.xml ;
echo (//KeyProviderType) ;
```

BTW, I had to fix 2 tags that were missing `>` in your input.

Comment: @user2465903: No, I don't use `grep` for XML.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `gnu awk` (due to RS)

```
awk -v RS="KeyProviderType" 'NR%2==0 {gsub(/>|<\//,"");print}' file
HLS-AES-128
```

Comment: Is this a school work?  Does you system not have `sed` `awk` and other utilities?  This is only a suggestion to help you out.  And as Chorobo writes `grep` may not be the correct tool for this. With reputation score of only  `6`, you should listen to people with more experience.

Answer (score 0):

You may use regex lookahead's and lookbehind's, provided your grep support -P flag.

```
cat s.xml | grep -oP "(?<=<KeyProviderType>).*(?=</KeyProviderType>)"
```